# Django compressor file name and hash

Tags: django, django-compressor

I was wondering if it's possible to have filename + hash .css / .js instead of only hash .css / .js.

ex : base.css -> base-23849098.css instead of 23849098.css

Right now I have only the hash .css / .js and it is very inconvenient for debugging.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no. But you can disable compressing while you debugging.
If you do not manually toggle this variable, you can make it smarter and add in the end of the settings file something like that:

```
if DEBUG:
    COMPRESS_ENABLED = False
```

And you will be able to debug your code more conviniently.